# jQuery scroll to top of iOS address bar

Tags: jquery, ios, scroll, jquery-animate

jQuery's `.animate({ scrollTop: '0' }, 600 });` scrolls iOS to the top of the page, but not to the absolute top (with address bar showing). Is there any way to goose it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$('body').scrollTop(0);` will set the scroll position of the page to the top of the page, while `$('body').scrollTop();` will return the current scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Will scroll to the top and will show the address bar
$('body').scrollTop();

// Will scroll to the top and won't show the address bar
$('body').animate({ scrollTop: '0' }, 0)
```